# Round and Rounded Rectangle border settings not saving in themes

Tags: themes, codenameone

I am finding some border settings for Round and Rounded Rectangle revert back to default when I next open my theme. I make the changes and save them fine however next time I open the theme I have to make the same changes again if I need to save anything new.

for instance: -
Round; opacity reverts back to 255 (been doing this for a while).
Rounded Rectangle (Round tab); Rectangle checkbox is always unticked so rounded edges become square (new in the last week or so)

Edit; I can see the Round opacity issue has been reported already
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2941

Comment: Did you update the project from Settings/Update Project Libs?

Comment: I have just tried update project libs however I still get the same behaviour. I have a  UIID called MyToggleButton which derives from ToggleButton. The unselected for MyToggleButton is set with Round border and opacity 100. It seems if I save the theme then return the opacity reverts back to 255.

Comment: Let me check, I think there might have been another fix for the designer this week in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Git.  It will be available in the update tomorrow.